# Javascript code alteration for a novice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have included my entire code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/37jfx) but can't get the jquery script to load properly in jsfiddle.
It works as it is supposed to at the moment in that the content of the "Post" are shown when it is clicked.
The modification I want is for the hidden post detail to be visible when the "uk" and "Post" options, BOTH, are selected. At the moment it only works when "Post" option is selected. thanks.
I am sure the line below needs to changed

```
if(this.value == 'Post')
```

Comment: this question is totally messed up, I do not understand it.

Comment: How can `this.value` be equal to *both* `'Post'` and `'uk'` at the same time?  You need to select the other radio button first and get its value.

Comment: So where's the other radio button, in your demo? And, incidentally, why is your relevant code not *here, in your question*?

Comment: K, I posted an answer but I bet this question will e closed for being unclear or not demonstrating a minimal understanding of the problem or.... something.  Just a warning.

Comment: You can't have two radio buttons (in the same group) selected at the same time. Use checkboxes instead.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/umefaz/97/edit?html,js,output

Comment: jackam Dont post your changes on @user623952 posts.  Make an edit section in your original post to maintain context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have two radios in the same group (with the same name) selected at the same time. If that's what you're trying to do then you should be using checkboxes instead.

If you have 2 checkboxes, then there are 4 possible states. Lets call the two checkboxes `A` and `B`. Here are the possible states (1 is checked, 0 is unchecked):

```
A | B
-----
1   0  // only A is checked
0   1  // only B is checked
0   0  // neither is checked
1   1  // A and B are both checked
```

The simplest way to handle this is with some `if/else`'s.

html:

```
<span id="msg">toggle some checkboxes</span>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="a_checkbox" /> A <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" id="b_checkbox"/>  B <br />
</div>
```

js:

```
var $a   = $("#a_checkbox"),
    $b   = $("#b_checkbox"),
    $msg = $("#msg");

$("input:checkbox").change(function () {

  var a_is_checked = $a.is(':checked'),
      b_is_checked = $b.is(':checked');

  if (a_is_checked && b_is_checked) {
    $msg.text('A and B are both checked');
  } else if (a_is_checked) {
    $msg.text('only A is checked');
  } else if (b_is_checked){
    $msg.text('only B is checked');
  } else {
    $msg.text('neither is checked');
  }
});
```

[demo](http://jsbin.com/umefaz/99/edit)

Assuming I understand your problem, this example contains everything you need to implement your own solution.

**Edit:**

html:

```
<span id="msg">Select A and C</span>

<!-- group 1 -->
<h2>Group 1</h2>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="A" /> A <br />
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="B" /> B <br />

<!-- group 2 -->
<h2>Group 2</h1>
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="C" /> C <br />
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="D" /> D <br />
```

js:

```
$(function(){

  var $group1 = $("input:radio[name='group1']"),
      $group2 = $("input:radio[name='group2']"),
      $msg    = $("#msg");  

  $("input:radio").change(function () {
    var group1_val = $group1.filter(':checked').val(),
        group2_val = $group2.filter(':checked').val();

    if (group1_val === "A" && group2_val === "C") {
      $msg.text("A and C are both selected");
    } else {
      $msg.text("Select A and C");
    }
  });

});
```

[demo](http://jsbin.com/umefaz/104/edit)

Comment: Can you please have another look. i have edited my question. Thanks.

Comment: @jackam I added another example.

Comment: Hi many thanks for your reply. I almost there, can you just please tell me how to display a <div> instead of the message.

Comment: @jackam just use `$msg.show()` and `$msg.hide()` (replace `$msg` with the `div`)

Comment: Your are the best. Many thanks for taking the time to solve my problem when many many others just were happy to pass a comment. Your work and effort is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that there are several ways to do this... I just did this the way that used as much as your original code, js logic and html structure as possible.  The new textbox has an ID of group_list.

(look at the bottom for the most recent edit)

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>



<div id="send_to">
  <input type="radio" id="send_poll" name="people" value="all" checked="checked" />all the attendees<br/>      
  <input type="radio" id="send_poll" name="people" value="one" />only one attendee<br/>
    <div id="send_to_one">
      <label>Write the attendee's name: </label><input type="text" id="attendeename" /><br/><br/>
    </div>
  <input type="radio" id="send_poll" name="people" value="group" />a group of attendees<br/>          
    <div id="send_to_group">
      <label>Write the groups's names: </label><input type="text" id="group_list" /><br/><br/>
    </div>     


</body>
</html>
```

**css**

```
#send_to_one{display:none;}

#send_to_group{display:none;}
```

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#send_to_one").hide();

    $("input:radio[name='people']").change(function(){  

            if(this.value == 'one' && this.checked){
              $("#send_to_one").show();
            }else{
              $("#send_to_one").hide();
            }

            if(this.value == 'group' && this.checked){
              $("#send_to_group").show();
            }else{
              $("#send_to_group").hide();
            }

    });
});
```

**To open/close the SAME div... just modify your original JQuery to be:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#send_to_one").hide();

    $("input:radio[name='people']").change(function(){  

            if((this.value == 'one' || this.value == 'group' ) && this.checked){
              $("#send_to_one").show();
            }else{
              $("#send_to_one").hide();
            }

    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your post. the problem is that my other ,<div> is not in the same one as <div id="send_to">.

Comment: @jackam - do you want the same div to be open? I did it like that initially but it just looked wrong and confusing. I updated my answer for you, check the bottom.

Comment: I have now included my entire code in http://jsfiddle.net/37jfx/ but can't get the <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script> loaded to it. All I want is for the hidden post detail to be visible when the "uk" and "Post" options, BOTH are selected. At the moment it only works when "Post" option is selected. thanks

Comment: Can someone please have a fresh look at my question. thanks in advance.

Comment: @jackam  - yeah,  I will in about 30 minutes.  can you try and get rid of those console errors in your jsfiddle first?

Comment: @jackam  the fiddle works if you just ad a closing bracket `}` to the function.   http://jsfiddle.net/vy2X3/

Comment: @jackam  also, for usability, you should make the labels select the radio buttons.  the hover area turns blue, right?  well, I should be able to click anywhere in that blue hover area to select that radio button.  it's what the user would expect to happen.  hover over your choice - then click. as it is, it took me 1-2 tries to realize you can't select the radio by it's label.  i thought the whole thing was broken.